# IE9 - Issue with JQuery Animate

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Here is the structure of my html:

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/fm2pgs6j/15/

```
<div id="mainConainer">

 <div id="section1"><a> HYPERLINK Will cause Section1 to slide towards 
left and hide . **DetailsSection** will be shown</div>

 <div id="detailSection"><a> HYPERLINK  On showinng if you click on 
this hyperlinkg this section will slide right,disappear and show section 1</div>

</div>
```

Code :

```
someFunction(){
Line 1. $("#section1").animate({left:'-100%'},500);
Line 2. Append the MainContainer with an AJAX Loading Image
Line 3. Load Detail Section via AJAX detailSection.promise.always(....);
line 4. Once loaded hide the AJAX image (Inside always of line 3) }
```

However, what is happening is that , until detailSection is loaded (via Ajax) the animation does not happen.

Any Clues ? I have to use this as "transition" property does not work in IE9

Comment: Could you just give your jQuery code? It's hard to tell what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Create a fiddle. It would be easier for us to find and understand the issue.

Comment: @BramVanroy JSFiddle has been created